# Can anonymous users upload files in Microsoft forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, limitations, microsoft-forms

Can anonymous users upload files in Microsoft forms?

If not, does anyone know any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not an official method but you can create unique upload codes through this link through power automate [RTFileUpload](https://realtech-auto.co.uk/RTFileUpload/Documentation.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a known limitation of file upload feature in Microsoft forms.

Anonymous users cannot upload files in forms created using Microsoft forms.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Attachment upload field in Forms](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/attachment-upload-field-in-forms/m-p/389133)
2. [Attachments to Microsoft Forms - for anonymous users](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/attachments-to-microsoft-forms-for-anonymous-users/m-p/2820895)

You can vote on this feedback/idea: [External Users be able to upload files](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/5e69ec76-d01c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8945)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. So it seems i need to check out google forms